# Number of zero eigenvalues of a matrix always equals to the nullity of that matrix?

Tags: matrices

I am studying linear algebra, the famout MIT 18.065 online course. In lecture [5 Positive Definite and Semidefinite Matrices](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xsP-S7yKaRA&list=PLUl4u3cNGP63oMNUHXqIUcrkS2PivhN3k&index=7), at 41:20, the prof used
[image] as an example to show why it has eigenvalues [3, 0, 0].

He explained that because this matrix has rank 1, it has 2 zero eigenvalues(he did not say it but I think he meant it), and because the trace is 3, the last eigenvalue is 3.

But is this really true that Number of zero eigenvalues of a matrix always equals to the nullity(n-rank) of that matrix?  For example, matrix [image] has 2 zero eigenvalues but its rank is 1.

I am a little confused about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every real symmetric matrix is diagonalizable and therefore, yes, its nullity is equal to the multiplicity of $0$ as a root of its characteristic polynomial. However, this is not true in general, as your example shows.